# How to stop a node js server from user

Tags: node.js, flask, server

My flask server starts at port 5000 and from there another node js server starts from port 3000 and opens a new window. I want when the users closes the node js window, it should stop node js server and go back to the flask app where it was.

Comment: on close event window?

Answer (score 0):

1.node listen a signal, exit when receives the signal

```
//node express
app.get('/kill', (req, res) => {
   server.close(() => {
    console.log('Process terminated')
  })
})
```

then use python request the route

Read More:
https://flaviocopes.com/node-terminate-program/

2.You can use shell to kill node server(or use python exec shell)

```
pid=$(sudo netstat -anp|grep 3000|awk '{printf $7}'|cut -d/ -f1)
kill $pid
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.
May be I did not make myself clear. From node js, a browser window opens. So I want when the user closes the browser window, the node js server should stop and the flask server retrieve work back where it was.